# $.fn chain method - call on a variable

Tags: jquery

## Question - brief

Can you call a jQuery method in a chain, from a variable, or can you only use these methods on jQuery objects / elements?

## Explanation

we have a custom function

```
$.fn.example = function(){
    $.each(this, (index, item) => {
        console.log(item);
    }
    return this;
}
```

This will loop through an object and `console.log()` each item within.

Let's say there are 3 `<p>` tags within the HTML.

```
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
```

If we call `$('p').example()` the elements `<p>One</p>`, `<p>Two</p>`, `<p>Three</p>` will be logged to the Console, one after the other.

## Question - continued

Does this type of method chaining *only* work with jQuery Objects, like the above, or is there a way to call this method on a variable?

e.g.

```
let someArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

someArray.example();
```

The above code will not work, as `example()` is not a method of `someArray`

## Question - final

Is there a correct way to call a jQuery method, in a chain, *from* a variable or object, or can you only call these methods on objects that have been "selected" with jQuery.

If you must first "select" the object with jQuery, is there a way to select a variable, rather than an element of the DOM.

Comment: Fantastic answers everyone, really helped me understand how this all works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong what you want to achieve can be done with `$(someArray).example();`.

Just try as following.

```js
$.fn.example = function(){
    $.each(this, (index, item) => {
        console.log(item);
    });
    return this;
}

let someArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

$(someArray).example();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether it's a variable or not isn't the issue. The issue is what you're interacting with.

You've added `example` to `jQuery.fn`, which means it's available on jQuery objects, and not on other kinds of objects, but that's because of what you've specifically done: Added it to the object that jQuery objects use as their prototype.

You can do that with arrays, too:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "example", {
    value: function() {
        // Your code here
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Live Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "example", {
    value: function() {
        this.forEach(entry => {
            console.log(entry);
        });
        return this;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
array.example();
```

**But**, modifying built-in prototypes comes with some **major** caveats:

- Always define the new properties you're adding as *non-enumerable* (the above does that by using `Object.defineProperty`, which by default adds non-enumerable properties).
- Always pick names that are unlikely to be used by future JavaScript enhancements. `example` is unlikely to be used in for future JavaScript enhancements, but generally best to use some kind of completely-unique prefix.
- If you're writing a library meant to be used by other people, it's best not to modify built-in prototypes **at all**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap the array in `$()` since `$.fn['methodName']` only chains to jQuery objects

```js
$.fn.example = function(){
    $.each(this, (index, item) => {
        console.log(item);
    })
    return this;
}

let someArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

$(someArray).example();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the suggestion of @Karan. This is the best way. But if you want to add a method to prototype of the Array, you can do this. But please be careful. Read first why you should not do this: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Here is a code you want:

```
Array.prototype.example = function () {
    this.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}

let someArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

someArray.example();
```

But this is not an good idea!